# MVC Devexpress Gridview Columns, how to add multiple settings to a specific column?

Tags: gridview, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I am attempting to add more than one setting to my mvc grid view columns.  I know how to apply one specific setting to a column.  I went through their website documentation and was unable to find an example of this.  I know it can be done and is probably really easy but can't find an example of it anywhere.

```
@{
 var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "gvMyGridView";
        settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
        //Allows sorting etc
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "MyGridPartial" };
        settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "OnBeginCallback";

        settings.Columns.Add("ColumnA").SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
        //settings.Columns.Add("ColumnA").Width = Unit.Pixel(75);
        //As you can see above i want sort order set and the width set but am unable to do so
        settings.Columns.Add("ColumnB").Width = Unit.Pixel(175);
        settings.Columns.Add("ColumnC").Width = Unit.Pixel(175);

        //Filter settings
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Visible = true;

        //Inline editing 
        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";

    });

    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null){
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

My example above is pretty self explanatory.  Maybe I have to create my column on its own add properties to it then add it in manually.  Unsure as this is my first run with MVC Devexpress Gridviews.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
column.FieldName = "Title";
column.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(30);
column.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
//other settings for column
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
var column = settings.Columns.Add("ColumnA", "ColumnADisplay");
column.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
column.Width = Unit.Pixel(75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to create the column myself.

```
var column = new MVCxGridViewColumn("ColumnA", MVCxGridViewColumnType.Default);
column.Caption = "ColumnADisplay";
column.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
column.Width = Unit.Pixel(75);        
settings.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with:

```
settings.Columns.Add(new MVCxGridViewColumn("ColumnA", MVCxGridViewColumnType.Default)
{
  Caption = "ColumnADisplay", 
  vSortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending,
  Width = Unit.Pixel(75)
});
```